# Installed lxml causes a TypeError when using another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

So I have this piece of code that (without lxml installed) works as expected

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring
from xmljson import badgerfish as bf

dic = {'p': {'@id': 'main'}}

output = bf.etree(dic, root=Element('root'))
print(tostring(output).decode('utf-8'))
```

the output is

```
<root><p id="main" /></root>
```

The problem is that I need lxml for another task, but if I install it (via pip install lxml) the above code produces this error

```
TypeError: append() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not lxml.etree._Element
```

So how can I use the above code with lxml?

Full stack trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7478b75b9581> in <module>
      4 dic = {'p': {'@id': 'main'}}
      5 
----> 6 output = bf.etree(dic, root=Element('root'))
      7 print(tostring(output).decode('utf-8'))

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xmljson/__init__.py in etree(self, data, root)
    132                     if elem is None:
    133                         continue
--> 134                     result.append(elem)
    135                     # Treat scalars as text content, not children (Parker)
    136                     if not isinstance(value, (self.dict, dict, self.list, list)):

TypeError: append() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not lxml.etree._Element
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Comment: Looks like you need to pass a lxml `Element` object to `bf.etree()` instead. The xmljson library automatically loads lxml if it's available.

Comment: One option is to use virtualenvs to separate the project you need `lxml` for from the project you need `xmljson` for, but this is fragile (as you saw) and only works if you don't actually need them both for this same project.

Comment: @jordanm fixed it importing lxml.etree.Element as EElement, thanks. Now I will post the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jordanm suggested, I have to pass an lxml Element to bf.etree() instead of an xml.etree Element, so the working code is

```
from lxml.etree import Element as EElement
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring
from xmljson import badgerfish as bf

dic = {'p': {'@id': 'main'}}

output = bf.etree(dic, root=EElement('root'))
print(tostring(output).decode('utf-8'))
```

that produces the correct output

```
<root><p id="main" /></root>
```